# C# creating new XML file appends old 'deleted' XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am successfully creating an XML file, however, if the user attempts to create a new XML in the attempt to overwrite the previous version, it instead appends the data; not overwrite.

What is giving me trouble in understanding this is that I first check if the file exists prior to creating the XML file, if it does exist, I delete it and then create the new XML file. I ran my code through the debugger and looked at the directory of where the file is being stored and I can clearly see the file being created, then deleted, and then be recreated.

```
        // Create new KML file
        string filepath = STK_TEMP + "/" + stkObjectClass + "-" + stkObjectName + ".kml";

        if(File.Exists(filepath))
            File.Delete(filepath);

        StreamWriter xmlsteam = new StreamWriter(filepath);

        using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlsteam))
        {
            xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xmlWriter.Indentation = 2;

            // Open KML file for appending data
            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

            // Write KML
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("kml", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Document");
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("name");
            xmlWriter.WriteString(stkObjectName);
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Placemark");

            // Append data from LLA / KML position report
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("LineString");
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("altitudeMode");
            xmlWriter.WriteString("absolute");
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("coordinates");
            xmlWriter.WriteString(kmlCoordinateString);

            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Coordinates
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Point  
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Placemark

            bool isFirstPoint = true;
            double seconds = 0;

            // Create individual poitns for Google Earth playback
            foreach (string kmlPoint in kmlCoordinateList)
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Placemark");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Style");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("IconStyle");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Icon");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("href");

                xmlWriter.WriteString("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png");

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END href  
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Icon  
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END IconStyle  
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Style

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TimeStamp");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("when");
                xmlWriter.WriteString(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"));
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END when  
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END TimeStamp

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Point");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("altitudeMode");
                xmlWriter.WriteString("absolute");
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END altitudeMode
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("coordinates");
                xmlWriter.WriteString(kmlPoint);
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END coordinates

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Point  
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END Placemark

                seconds++;
            }

            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END KML

            // END KML file and close
            xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xmlWriter.Flush();
            xmlWriter.Close();
    }

    xmlsteam.Dispose();
```

If I close out of my application and start it up and trying creating the file, it will overwrite it on the first attempt. Leaving the application open and trying to create a new file with the same file path, it just appends the data.

Any thoughts?

I feel that my XmlTextWriter is not being disposed of properly...

[image]

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: can we see where you check if the file exists and delete it

Comment: Sure thing. Also added the folder of where I am storing my file. It does delete the file ( I used a break point to ensure it was removed from the directory), and then when I create, it adds in the new information ontop of the old information that was stored in the 'deleted' version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the assignment of `xmlsteam` to the following:

```
StreamWriter xmlsteam = new StreamWriter(filepath, false);
```

Adding `false` as a parameter forces it to overwrite the file instead of appending:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

As an added measure, add the following line right after creating `xmlsteam`:

```
xmlsteam.AutoFlush = true;
```

This will make sure that all buffers for the file are automatically flushed after each file operation.

After looking into this further, I think the problem lies in that you are calling `xmlsteam.Dispose()` before disposing of the resources that depend on it.  You should modify the end of your code to the following:

```
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // END KML

        // END KML file and close
        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        xmlWriter.Close();

    }  // end of 'using' block

xmlsteam.Dispose();
```

Comment: I added this, but it still is appending the data. Even after the file is deleted, it as if my program coughs the old file back up and adds the data rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Likewise, its still adding data to the 'Deleted' file. It is as if it still has the data from the previous file stored in memory but I don't get how that is possible.

Comment: I did indeed set a break point and the file is definitely deleted.

Comment: I did all of those expect xmlWriter.Dispose(). I stated in my code: using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlsteam)) which explicity calls dispose at the end of the code block.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're disposing of the base stream of `xmlWriter` before the `xmlWriter` itself is disposed of.  You should at least move the `xmlsteam.Dispose();` out of the `using` block.

Comment: Still, no such luck : ( 

I made changes accordingly and still it keeps regurgitating information from the deleted file. Maybe I shall try creating an xml file using XMLDocument...

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
StreamWriter xmlsteam = new StreamWriter(filepath,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [StreamWriter constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx). The second parameter determines whether or nor an existing file is overwritten or appended to. From the docs, pass

> true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my problem... unfortunately it was a very careless mistake on my part. The data being stored within my variables are not being reset upon creating/overwriting an existing file.

Thank you all for trying to assist me with this issue.

Comment: That would make sense...  Glad you figured it out.